# Remove render blocking

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress site, I have to check render-blocking with google page speed.

Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:

```
/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/css/language-selector.css?v=3.4.1   
/wp-content/themes/premium-theme/style.css   
/wp-content/themes/premium-theme-child/style.css  
http://fonts.googleapis.com/…300%2C400%2C600%2C700%2C900&subset=latin
```

I actually use "BWP Minify" to combine some others css, but here are the remains, it might be because the plugin couldn't detect those.

I have to combine all css in 1 file or as least as possible.But I don't understand, The css files are located in different plugins, themes folders. how can we combine it? I found a lot of tutorial to inline and copy them in 1 file but I can not do that in wordpress.

- I also try to defer css to help solve it but no success with this                                                                    [git hub](https://gist.github.com/schilke/02357d9263ed28fc1769)!

  I use the last code in my child- functions.php

if anyone has experience, please help me.

Comment: Just a minor question but, do you actually use all of those subsets for your google font? 300, 400, 600, 600 **and** 900 is a bit much.

Comment: I think its from the parent theme.